# "Could not find specified module" error SetWindowsHookEx

Tags: c#, .net, setwindowshookex

I want my program to be able to detect mouse clicks while it is minimized and not in focus at all.  I found on CodePlex a library called Gma.UserActivityControl and I downloaded that.  I can build their project just fine and their demo does exactly what I want.  I then took the UserActivityProject (not including the demo project) and added it to my solution.  However, when I try to run my program it crashes and throws error

> 126 - The specified module could not be found

I googled this and found that there were some changes made between differing versions of .NET, I also found what I thought was a solution.  Someone had suggested to use LoadLibrary("user32") instead of the Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(...), and this fixed the crash; however the functionality is different.  It still hooks the mouse, I have it set to update a counter on my app whenever a button is pressed, however if I minimize my program or if it loses focus it does not update anymore (which was not the case with their demo and that is the functionality I need)

Does anyone have a fix for this so that I can achieve the functionality of the UserActivityDemo application?

EDIT:

I have found out my issue.  I was using the title of the windows to update the counter and when I saw that wasn't updating I thought that my code was not working.  I changed the counter to be a label on the form and it updates even while in the background!  Silly mistake.

Comment: Could you post a link to the application?

Comment: When you find the solution to your problem, post it as an answer. Don't edit the question to include the answer, because the system considers the question unanswered and won't suggest it to other people with the same question.